# relay modern run RefetchContainer only manually

Tags: relayjs, relay, relaymodern

I still don't have much experience with relay modern and am trying to implement a search.

For this I use a "RefetchContainer":

```
export default createRefetchContainer(
    SearchComponent,
    {
    base: graphql`
      fragment SearchComponent_base on Base
      @argumentDefinitions(
        input: {type: "FireSearchInput!" defaultValue: {page: 0,queryString:""}}
        )
            {                
                    search(input: $input){
                    total
                    ...SearchResult_searchResult
                    }
            }
      `
    },
    graphql`
    query SearchComponentRefetchQuery($input: FireSearchInput!) {        
        ...SearchComponent_base @arguments(input: $input)
     }
    `
)
```

The problem is only that the query is already execute when you start the app, without an input is made.

Is it possible to suppress the automatic query and execute it only with the command `this.props.relay.refetch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to simply use a `QueryRenderer`:

```
<QueryRenderer
  environment={environment}
  query={graphql`
    query SearchComponent($input: FireSearchInput!) {
        search(input: $input){
             total
             ...SearchResult_searchResult
           }
    }
  `}
  variables={{
    input: {///my input}
  }}
```